# Should I show the user how many views its content has received?

Tags: users, emotion

If the user uploads a content of any type (video,photo,url,text) should I show him how many times it has been viewed even though other parameters such as e.g. Kudos,Likes and Shares are available to let him know about the popularity/appreciation of it?

I was wondering how would this affect the user emotionally, e.g. the user has 300 people to whom the content can be showed, from where 200 saw his content yet only 20 people "Liked" or "Kudos" it.

In this cases would it be considered a better option to avoid completely showing him such data to avoid a negative emotional response? Or would it actually give him meaningful data to create better content?

**UPDATE 1 :** It also comes to my mind to consider the behavior of the spectators knowing that the content uploader receives such stat, would they feel more inclined to "Like" or "Kudo" content? And would this distress them given the amount of content that they are receiving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I don't believe the ratio of views to "likes/kudos"
will negatively affect the user**.

The way I see it the internet is successful because it gives average people the ability to reach tons of people they normally wouldn't be able to. Being able to see how many people you reached makes it worth posting content for them to see. If you posted an article and all the feedback you received was "11 likes" you would be less likely to post again than if you saw "12 million views, 11 likes". Just the fact that that many people acknowledged your work makes it worthwhile.

See SE for example:

[image]

I probably have less than 100 upvotes on my questions and answers. But SE informs me that roughly 32k people have seen what I've done. I'm not discouraged that each one of them didn't like my posts, thats just the way it is. **Knowing that I can impact that many people makes me want to post more and better content.**

Comment: Good answer, I'll be giving the users the stat and I'll monitor their activity after positive and negative outcomes in relation to views and explicit appreciation, I'll remember to publish my findings here. Cheers.

Comment: Please do, always love to see some good A/B test results. Thanks.